# fatal IO error 22 (Invalid argument) on X server ":0"

Tags: display, 20.04, opencv

When trying to do openCV subplot on my Ubuntu 20.04 I get the following error

```
The X11 connection broke: Maximum allowed requested length exceeded (code 4)
XIO:  fatal IO error 22 (Invalid argument) on X server ":0"
      after 459 requests (455 known processed) with 0 events remaining.
```

This error appears only when using external , when using internal display I don't get this error

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a high resolution external monitor? If so, you might be hitting the same issue that I am: there seems to be some kind of issue in QT and high DPI scaling. This would also explain the change in behavior when you use your internal display.

I was able to fix it by setting the environment variable `QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0`

---

I discovered this via scattered mentions in a few GitHub issues for projects using QT, such as [this response to problems running `cantata`](https://github.com/CDrummond/cantata/issues/1066#issuecomment-330071920):

> [potuz](https://github.com/potuz) commented on Sep 17, 2017:
>
> > After finding this out, I found a closed issue [#1073](https://github.com/CDrummond/cantata/issues/1073) and running with
> >
> > ```
> > $ QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0 cantata
> > ```
> >
> > It works as expected.

---

For context, I'm running a 5120x1440 monitor, and my error was triggered by trying to create a `matplotlib` plot in Python. [This problem I had running `anaconda-navigator`](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10467#issuecomment-655791695) about a month ago also seems directly related to high DPI scaling.